# SQL sub select returning multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I want to count future *Appointments* made on the same day of an active appointment by *Location*. I expect multiple counts per *Patient_ID* given a date range. I am not sure if I need a temp table or if a subquery would work.

From the code below this is the error I get:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Definitions:

- Appointment_DateTime - (Date) is the actual appointment event
- DateTime_Scheduled - (Date) is the logging timestamp of future appointments
- Description - (text) is the Location Description
- Patient_ID - (int) is the unique patient ID
- Appointment_ID - (int) is the unique Appointment ID

SQL

```
SELECT
  loc.Description
 ,Count(app.Appointment_ID)

 FROM [Ntier_HARH].[PM].[Appointments] app

 join [Ntier_HARH].[PM].[Resources] res 
    on res.Resource_ID = app.Resource_ID
 join [Ntier_HARH].[PM].[Practitioners] doc 
    on doc.Practitioner_ID = res.Practitioner_ID
 join [Ntier_HARH].[PM].[Scheduling_Locations] loc 
    on loc.Scheduling_Location_ID = app.Scheduling_Location_ID

 where      
   cast(app.DateTime_Scheduled as date) = '2017-01-16' 
     and app.status <> 'X'
     and cast(app.Appointment_DateTime as date) = 
       (Select cast(DateTime_Scheduled as date) 
        from [Ntier_HARH].[PM].[Appointments] 
        where Patient_ID = app.Patient_ID)

 group by loc.Description
```

Comment: Looking at the query, I believe you need `min` or `max` aggregate in sub query or you can use `Row_Number` to avoid sub-query

Comment: Don't you also need to group by the PatientId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `in` instead of `=`

```
where 

 cast(app.DateTime_Scheduled as date) = '2017-01-16' 
 and app.status <> 'X'
 and cast(app.Appointment_DateTime as date) IN (Select cast(DateTime_Scheduled as date) from [Ntier_HARH].[PM].[Appointments] where Patient_ID = app.Patient_ID)

 group by loc.Description
```

Comment: That was it! Boy was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you also need to group by the PatientId?  If you want the count of appointments by location only, then the subquery isn't necessary. I don't see why the other two tables are necessary either.

```
SELECT l.Description, Count(a.Appointment_ID)

FROM [Ntier_HARH].[PM].[Appointments] a
   join [Ntier_HARH].[PM].[Scheduling_Locations] l 
      on l.Scheduling_Location_ID = a.Scheduling_Location_ID

where cast(a.DateTime_Scheduled as date) = '2017-01-16' 
   and a.status <> 'X'

group by l.Description
```

Comment: I only wanted to count Appintment_ID if the Dates matched on a per patient_ID and not any date that matched.